# Schedule background task when after every 30 seconds - react-native

Tags: react-native, background-task

I want to schedule background task that run after every 30 seconds using react-native

I have seen the following libraries

1. [react-native-background-job](http://%20https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job)
2. [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)
3. [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)

but all of them a limitation i.e I cannot set frequency to run the job less than 15 minutes.

I have also checked [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) but it doesn't seem to work when app is terminated.

How can I achieve background task which can be scheduled after every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using react-native-background-job npm.

> https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job/blob/master/example/index.js

Refer that code for example.

You also need to add foreground permission in your androidManifest.xml (android/app/src/main).

> < uses-permission android:name
>   ="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Add that line above "<"application">" tag

Comment: The Npm uses "headless JS", which is currently supported only on Android.

Comment: I want to schedule task in both ios and android  after every 30 seconds

Comment: Job is not triggering at all, how can I make it work? https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job/issues/169 I have tried referring your code @tejase

Comment: Actually I also need some suggetions for backgroud-job package .... I'm unable to use it

Comment: Did you try adding foreground permission? sorry for replying late @Prajna